# Regular expression to scrape string between html tags in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am trying to extract price from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1 and element:

```
<title>GOOG 989.68 1.85 0.19% : Alphabet Inc. - Yahoo Finance</title>
```

But my output doesn't contain the price of 989.68. Instead I get this:

```
['GOOG : Summary for Alphabet Inc. - Yahoo Finance']
```

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request 
import re

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG");

htmltext = htmlfile.read();

pattern = re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>');

price = pattern.findall(str(htmltext));
print(price);
```

Comment: Protip - Semicolons are not required in Python, and should not be used.

Comment: Have you considered using: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance ? (disclaimer: haven't checked it works but looks like it might)

Comment: `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\%?)` shows proper return values

Comment: Regular expressions are not able to parse HTML correctly. Use a parser. Python has more than one available.

Comment: @rindel, what exactly do you want your expected output to be?

Comment: I want the output to be the current price of GOOG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see any stock information in the `<title></title>`, but I was able to get it to work using BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
container = soup.select_one('div#quote-header-info')

print(container.find('h1').text)

for ele in container.find_all('span'):
    print(ele.text)
```

which has an output of

```
GOOG - Alphabet Inc.
NasdaqGS - NasdaqGS Delayed Price. Currency in USD
989.68
+1.85 (+0.19%)
At close:  4:00PM EDT
```

I would highly recommend **not** using `data-reactid` to find your element, as that can and is very likely to change after new releases to the website. It's an internal ID used by the [React](https://reactjs.org/) framework. Furthermore, in some browsers, React doesn't even put the react-id as an attribute, but rather as `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

The price isn't actually contained in the title. Go to the page source and see for yourself. Its much simpler if you just use BeautifulSoup instead of re:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# Use this to look at the source code
# print soup.prettify()

# Here is the exact tag of the span containing the price, 
# not sure if it'll be the same every time
for span in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'}):
    price = span.text
    break

print price

989.68

# Here is a more generic tag for the span, the value for this can change as well, 
# but its a simpler change. The price is contained in the first span like this, 
# so a break will make sure you get the correct one
for span in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'data-reactid': '14'}):
    price = span.text
    break

print price

989.68
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression is possible to get the items you need. Here is the code.

```
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()

# for the title
pattern = re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>')
title = pattern.findall(str(htmltext))
print('title:',title[0])

# regularMarketPrice
pattern = re.compile('\"regularMarketPrice\":{\"raw\":(.*?),')
regularMarketPrice = pattern.findall(str(htmltext))
print('regularMarketPrice:', regularMarketPrice[0])

# regularMarketChange
pattern = re.compile('\"regularMarketChange\":{\"raw\":(.*?),')
regularMarketChange = pattern.findall(str(htmltext))
print('regularMarketChange:',regularMarketChange[0])

# regularMarketChangePercent
pattern = re.compile('\"regularMarketChangePercent\":{\"raw\":(.*?),')
regularMarketChangePercent = pattern.findall(str(htmltext))
print('regularMarketChangePercent:',regularMarketChangePercent[0])  # x100 to get percent

# for close time
pattern = re.compile('<span data-reactid="21">At close:(.*?)</span>')
at_close = pattern.findall(str(htmltext))
print('At close:',at_close[0])
```

The output:

```
('title:', 'GOOG : Summary for Alphabet Inc. - Yahoo Finance')
('regularMarketPrice:', '989.68')
('regularMarketChange:', '1.8499756')
('regularMarketChangePercent:', '0.0018727671')
('At close:', '  4:00PM EDT')
```

Comment: Swatchai, when I try your suggestion via regex I get
title: GOOG : Summary for Alphabet Inc. - Yahoo Finance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\scrapetest3_regex.py", line 20, in <module>
    print('regularMarketPrice:', regularMarketPrice[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Actually it works for other stocks or mutual funds such as IBM but not for GOOG.

Comment: @rindel Thanks for the feedback. I have corrected the error, please try again. Always remember that using regular expression is also good for this kind of task, it is available in all major programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this as well to get the desired output without using regex:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1').text, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select("div#quote-header-info"):
    title = item.select("h1")[0].text
    price = [elem.text for elem in item.select("span")[1:3]]
    print("Name: {}\nClosing Status: {}".format(title,' '.join(price)))
```

Results:

```
Name: GOOG - Alphabet Inc.
Closing Status: 989.68 +1.85 (+0.19%)
```

Answer (score -1):

I've gone through the html source of the page url that you 'vementioned. As you said the price is loaded in the title with the help of javascript. If you examine the html source you can see the script before the title tag. since whenever you make requests to a website using a script it returns you the html code as response. Python scripts do not understand javascripts hence price is not loaded in the title. I recommend you to go with requests library for making requests sinse it hs got advance features.[requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). As others I would suqggest you to use `BeautifulSoup` for parsing `html`. It is easy to understand.[BeautifulSoup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Use `lxml` parser. So if you follow these in script your code should be

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG?ltr=1"
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.contemt,"lxml")
price=soup.find("span",{"data-reactid":"35"}).text
print price
```

This should return the price as expected.